# Icon is not shown in ActionBar

Tags: java, android

#### I'm building an Android application that has an icon in its ActionBar, like this:

[image]

I'm following exactly what says in Android's docs and tutorials and my result is just a text, in any screen size / resolution: 
 
[image]

**I'm doing the following**:

`-> MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

`-> main_activity_actions.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

I put the icon in `*/res/drawable-*` and it is recognized, but it is shown as just a text in my menu. As you can see, I explicit specify `android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"` and I receive only `"Search"`. What can I do about this? I'm using API level 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tony,

AS per the action bar guide:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems, we have to use app:showAsAction="ifRoom" or app:showAsAction="always". IF you have to show the search Icon at any cost, go with showAsAction="always", though your name is lengthy it will be truncated with dots if your app name has no room

[image: FYI, Please check my sample app]

[image]

please check my xml file, which has two extra namespaces which will help you with to use the app:showAsAction.

Answer (score 1):

Your title may be too long to use with `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"` try using `android:showAsAction="always"` though that may cause your title to be cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using actionbar compat 
in that case you have to add this name space  `xmlns:support="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`and then like this support:showAsAction="always"
your menu.xml should be like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:support="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        support:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        support:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

and 'support' is just use for namespace you can use other words also like 'app'etc